# Summing diagonals and retrieve the maximum value among them

Tags: algorithm, excel, excel-formula

I have this example data:
[image: SO19478826 question example]

I need to get maximum value as from summing groups of values in this data. What I want to sum is:

First count from A1. In this case, I have 42.
Second, I just can go down and lower right diagonal.
Last, I must reach the end (line 25).

I need to get the maximum value among all diagonal summations.

How to do it in Excel?

Comment: This is a common programming puzzle, but I remember having fun figuring it out. Do you want the answer or a hint?

Answer (score 2):

Assuming your range is named `A` and starts at `A1`, try entering this formula in a free cell:

```
=MAX(MMULT(N(OFFSET(A,MOD(ROW(A)+COLUMN(A)-2,ROWS(A)),COLUMN(A)-1)),ROW(A)^0))
```

Comment: Awesome! By the way, the range doesn't have to start at A1.

Comment: i'm trying and get !value cell